# Is there a way to dynamically access a ref's properties in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a form with four file inputs. Different inputs for files with different purposes.

I have created a ref for each file.

I have created an array of the refs.

On submit, I was trying to access all of the refs and get their ref.current.files[0].

Example Code Below:

```
import {useRef} from 'react';

export default function myComponent(props){

const file1 = useRef(null);
const file2 = useRef(null);
const file3 = useRef(null);
const file4 = useRef(null);

const fileRefs = [file1, file2, file3, file4];

function onSubmit(){
  let files = [];

  fileRefs.map((ref) => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.fileName = ref.current.files[0].name;
    obj.file = ref.current.files[0];
    files.push(obj)
  })
}

render(
<div className="form">

<label>File 1 </label>
<input type="file" ref={file1} />

<label>File 2 </label>
<input type="file" ref={file2} />

<label>File 3 </label>
<input type="file" ref={file3} />

<label>File 4 </label>
<input type="file" ref={file4} />

<button onClick={() => onSubmit()}>Submit</button>

</div>
)
}
```

Error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')"

So, I can't access the .current property of a ref in this manner.

I don't really know how to approach this issue, was just trying to cobble something together.

If anyone could help me out with a way of dynamically accessing a ref's current properties, that would be great.

Comment: Where do you *actually* set any of the refs `current` value? What is calling `onSubmit`? Can you include all relevant code in your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited my code to include them. I'm not having an issue calling the function, or assigning the ref, so I left it out for brevity. My apologies.

Comment: Updated @DrewReese

Comment: Why are you using render in function component?

Comment: Are you selecting a file for each input? I.E. four file inputs, four selected files?

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin I just assumed this as a copy/paste typo since changing "render" to "return" the code runs.

Comment: I don't see any issue in accessing the refs dynamically: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-tree-xw1fi?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an issue in your code, per se, it works if you select a file for all file inputs. The issue only manifests if any input is left without a selected file.

To resolve this you can use the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to do a null check into the file object.

```
ref.current.files[0]?.name
```

If `ref.current.files[0]` is null or undefined then access into the file object is short-circuited and undefined is returned, otherwise, access is continued and the file name is returned.

Code:

```
function onSubmit() {
  const files = fileRefs.map((ref) => ({
    fileName: ref.current.files[0]?.name,
    file: ref.current.files[0],
  }));

  console.log({ files });
}
```

[image: Edit is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-access-a-refs-properties-in-react]

Answer (score 1):

In your code instead of **render** use **return**, you have used functional component where render function is not available.
Check this link for working solution
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-faraday-upg89?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah, I didn't copy the code. I rewrote it on the fly on stackoverflow. That's my bad. It was return in the actual code.